# Flutter running old app but not running new app

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

so i created a flutter app after i

> Flutter -upgrade

everything worked fine till i created an app and try to run it took too long then crash. i runned

> Flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1316], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.3 at C:\src\flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 4d7946a68d (4 days ago), 2021-03-18 17:24:33 -0700
    • Engine revision 3459eb2436
    • Dart version 2.12.2

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.20.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • MAR LX1A (mobile) • QTC4C19710005392 • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
    • Edge (web)        • edge             • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.57

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

this is what i got as output...

after that i searched google for solution and i didnt found anything sadly i tried to run

> flutter doctor --android-licenses

then i runned

> sdkmanager

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
```

and this is the output for both

please help me i am stuck and i need to find solutions so fast
thank you <3

Comment: Did you get any error when it crashed?

Comment: @VinayHP yeah an error telling me to run flutter doctor -v and see what missing
 i am trying to run it now but its taking so much time

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of the complete error.

Comment: @VinayHP it is stuck in 

Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 in C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 (revision: 29.0.2)".

Comment: go to this location C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses and delete licenses file and recompile. It might work as it creates a new file.

Comment: welp now its stuck in the Launching lib\main.dart on MAR LX1A in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1

Comment: @VinayHP i am tryning to install sdk manualy

Comment: welp the idea that my app is working now but in flutter doctor -v i still the have the licenses issue

Comment: @VinayHP i cant say how much i am happy that my app is working again thank you so much my man i appreciate what you did <3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solution was to run

> flutter clean

> flutter run

it helped me and fixed everything

and ofc as in the coments a guy helped me so thank him :3